# Preferred Order of NVRAM/PRAM, SMC, and OS resets

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management, nvram

Is there a preferred order in which I should reset the NVRAM/PRAM, SMC, and OS on my MBP?

If so, what is this order (and why)?

---

Edit: I intend to do all of them to completely reset my computer. No need to explain what each does, I know what they do.

Comment: It’s not clear what completely reset means, but dozens of people ask this so I’ll put a general answer and hope you don’t mind. I’m curious why you’re asking if you know what each does?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don’t do any of these until you have a very specific reason to do each. They handle entirely different functions so cycling through each of them would be equivalent to not even refining what you want to handle.

Take a medical analogy:

- bandages are for cuts
- anti-inflammatory is for swelling
- anti-pyretic is for fever
- rest and liquids are for colds
- antiboitics are for infections

Prescribing the wrong treatment just wastes time and can cause further injury if you’re not treating the actual problem at hand.

Comment: The answer would be better if it listed these very specific reasons. The medical metaphor is very imprecise.

Comment: How is it imprecise?  I think this answer makes a very clear analogy to emphasize the point that you use certain tools/procedures when you have particular symptoms.  You don’t use every medicine in your bag for every case.